# @JdbcInsert insert multiple entries

Tags: javascript, sql, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to insert an entry into my DB2 db by using JavaScript @JdbcInsert method. And it works perfect.

```
var myData={  
    DOCTYPE: "type",  
    DOCID: 1,  
    DOCNAME: "name"  
}

@JdbcInsert("db2", "MYTABLE", myData);
```

What I need is to insert multiple entries at a time.. So I need to change myData object somehow.. But how should I do that.. Assume I need something like

```
var myData={{  
    DOCTYPE: "type",  
    DOCID: 1,  
    DOCNAME: "name1"  
},{
    DOCTYPE: "type",  
    DOCID: 1,  
    DOCNAME: "name2"  
}}
```

but it doesn't really work..

Answer (score 0):

try this, var myData=[{
    DOCTYPE: "type",
    DOCID: 1,
    DOCNAME: "name1"
},{
    DOCTYPE: "type",
    DOCID: 1,
    DOCNAME: "name2"
}]

Comment: It doesn't work:   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-117, SQLSTATE=42802, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.7.85
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-117;42802;, DRIVER=4.7.85