# Why @jdbc query fails with connection timeout?

Tags: java, jdbc, xpages

Here is my code to insert rows into DB2 table:

```
for(i=0; i<1000000; i++){
    var myData = {
        USERNAME:   "user1",
        SOMEID:     i
    };
    @JdbcInsert("db2", "MYTABLE", myData);
}
```

at some point it fail with this error:

```
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=211, col=22: Error while executing function '@JdbcInsert'
Error while creating connection
Time expired getting a connection (=10000 ms). Try again.
```

As I found there is no way to control JDBC driver timeout. Am I wrong?
Or should I put something like

```
java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
```

before each @JdbcInsert statement?

Comment: i think you can change the server timeout.

Comment: however, 10 seconds should be more than enough to create a connection, in most cases it should be substantially faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would adding `Thread.sleep(1000)` fix your problem?  The issue here is that you are expecting to insert 1,000,000 records into a DB2 with a connection timeout of 10 seconds.

You need to either: A) increase your connection timeout or B) insert fewer records at a time (i.e. insert 10k or 100k records then get a new connection)

Obviously A sounds like the best solution here, since B just adds more overhead of getting additional connections.

Comment: I don't establish any connection. There is just one single JavaScript command @Jdbcinsert to insert a record. It's not pure Java where you can control everything. The problem would be fixed if I can insert multiple records at a time. But this question is still open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768736/jdbcinsert-insert-multiple-entries

Comment: right, if you used option B you would have to use some other mechanism besides `@Jdbcinsert` (i.e. something more fine grained that actually allows you to control connections)

Answer (score 0):

The .jdbc file has timeout parameters. See the Ext Lib book https://books.google.com/books?id=4DIXQKQNoSQC&pg=PA408&lpg=PA408&dq=xpages+jdbc+file+timeout&source=bl&ots=YJXuvWUJf0&sig=1bD_chX0IkEtSPvkfaSfZqJlSvk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsvI7cobHLAhUG92MKHcmNBCUQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=xpages%20jdbc%20file%20timeout&f=false